# Javascript and webservices security concerns

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, security

With **Javascript** becoming the language of the web there are many holes when it comes to security based on what I read online. One such hole is HTML injections as mentioned here:

http://deadliestwebattacks.com/category/html-injection/

I know most leading software industries are using Javascript and there will be best practices to avoid such attacks. My question is more when using jquery to communicate with web service. When I use `$.post` or `$.get` I have to actually expose the web service url in the code. If someone does a view source they the url will be exposed. Can this be considered threatful? If yes what are security measures to ensure that that threats can be eliminated or minimized.

Any thoughts/ suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Depending what you include in the url, it might or might not be a threat.

Comment: If you try to hide your site with security through obscurity, you're just going to be wasting your time. I can still look up all the network calls using Firebug or any other similar tool.

Comment: It's perfectly fine as long as you assume that any traffic hitting that endpoint is potentially evil (which is something you should always assume anyway).